# How to get content by table row and if non applicable append "None"?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a problem when iterating through many links. I scrape according to columns css selector. however, as it seems there is among all links not a rating for every player. How do I manage that I get a "None" for the home_rating list when there is among the eleven starting squad no rating available in a specific "player row".

I basically need to scrape all column entries per row. thanks a lot for your support.

```
gamedays_url = range(1,35)
url_list = []
daylinks = []
for gameday in gamedays_url:
        url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/premier-league/spieltag/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=2018&spieltag=" + str(gameday)
        url_list.append(url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
```

```
gameLinks = []
for i in range(len(url_list)):
    page = url_list
    tree = requests.get(page[i], headers = {'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(tree.content, 'html.parser')
    links_2 = soup_2.find_all("a", {"class": "liveLink"}, href=re.compile("spielbericht"))
    for j in range(len(links_2)):
            gameLinks.append(links_2[j].get('href').split('/')[4])
```

```
for j in range(len(gameLinks)):
        gameLinks[j] = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/spiele/aufstellung/spielbericht/" + gameLinks [j]
```

```
home_id = []
home_name = []
homerating = []

for p in range(len(gameLinks)):
    page = gameLinks[p]

    response = requests.get(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    lineup_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(lineup_data, 'html.parser')
    
    test =soup.find('div', class_='responsive-table')
    
    for homeid in test.find_all('a', href=re.compile('profil/spieler')):
       home_id.append(homeid.get('href').split('/')[4])
    
    for homename in test.find_all('a', href=re.compile('profil/spieler')):
        home_name.append(homename.get('href').split('/')[1])

    for grade in test.find_all('span', class_=None):
        homerating.append(grade.text.split()[0])
        homerating.append(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if your selected element is available and scrape the text alse set it to `None`:

```
row.select_one('span:not([class])').get_text(strip=True) if row.select('span:not([class])') else None
```

Also try to work with structured `dicts` instead of `list`.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
data = []
    
for gameday in range(1,3):
    url = "https://www.transfermarkt.de/premier-league/spieltag/wettbewerb/L1/plus/?saison_id=2018&spieltag=" + str(gameday)
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    for a in soup.select('a.liveLink[href*="spielbericht"]'):
        report_url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/spiele/aufstellung/spielbericht/'+a.get('href').split('/')[-1]
        response = requests.get(report_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

        for row in soup.select_one('table.items').select('tr:has(table)'):
            data.append({
                'home_id': row.select_one('a').get('href').split('/')[-1],
                'home_name': row.select_one('a img').get('title'),
                'home_rating': row.select_one('span:not([class])').get_text(strip=True) if row.select('span:not([class])') else None
            })

data
```

##### Output

```
[...{'home_id': '45672', 'home_name': 'Kevin Trapp', 'home_rating': '3,4'},{'home_id': '256866', 'home_name': 'Carlos Salcedo', 'home_rating': None},{'home_id': '58178', 'home_name': 'David Abraham', 'home_rating': '3,4'}, {'home_id': '146258', 'home_name': 'Jetro Willems', 'home_rating': '5,5'},...]
```